# Finding the diameter $d(X)$ of a set with closed balls.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Denote the diameter of set $X$ as $d(X)$ . Determine $d(X),$ when $X = \bar{B}(0,1) \cup \bar{B}(10e_1, 2)$.

It's quite easy to see that $d(X)=13$, but I cannot show this using the definitions.

If $d(X) = \sup\{d(x,y) \vert x,y \in X \}$ and $d(x,y) = \|x-y\|$. What can I do here?

If I can show that $X$ is a subset of a bigger ball would that help here?

If I take the ball $\bar{B}(\frac{11}{2}, \frac{13}{12})$ then I could show that $X \subset \bar{B}(\frac{11}{2}, \frac{13}{12})$.

Pick any $x \in \bar{B}(0,1)$. Looking at this graphically  it seems that $d(\frac{11}{2},x) \leqslant  d(\frac{11}{2},0) + d(0,x)$ would hold, but I'm not entirely sure. Here I could conclude that $X \subset \bar{B}(\frac{11}{2}, \frac{13}{12})$, which would let me bound $d(X)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must have $d(X)\geq 13$ since $(-1,0,\dots,0), (12,0,\dots,0)\in X$. Lets show it is infact the maximum itself. For all $x,y \in X$ we have that if they are in the same ball of center $c$ and radius $R$, it is obvious the distance can't go over the diameter of the ball$\leq 4$:
$$ \| x-y\| = \| x - c + c-y\| \leq \| x - c \| + \| c-y\|\leq R+R=2R\leq 4$$
The harder case is when they're in different balls (w.l.o.g $x\in \bar{B}(0,1)$), but it's the same technique
$$\| x-y\| = \| y-10e_1 + 10e_1 - 0 + 0 -x\|\leq  \| y-10e_1 \| +\| 10e_1 - 0 \|+\| 0 -x\|\leq2+10+1=13$$
So we get that we must have $d(X)\leq 13$ and so $d(X)=13$.